# Overriding ImageView minHeight dynamically

Tags: android, imageview

I have ImageView that is populated from url. When the image comes in I scale it using "centerInside" policy, which is nice and I adjust ImageView bounds to it using "adjustViewBounds".

Before I download the image I don't know the would-be size of the ImageView. However, I need to display a placeholder of reasonable size. So i put in "minHeight=150dp" with color background.

```
   <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/leadImageView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:minHeight="150dp"
                    android:background="@color/color_primary"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside" />
```

Now, this has a consequence that if the downloaded image would be smaller than 150 dp the ImageView will still occupy 150dp, that I don't want.

So what I have tried is to build a derived ImageView class that overrides minHeight if drawable is already present, like this:

```
class SomeImageView extends ImageView {
    protected int getSuggestedMinimumHeight() {
        if (getDrawable() != null)
            return 0;
        return super.getSuggestedMinimumHeight();
    }
}
```

I did it in different variations, but it seems that getDrawable() is null when it is really in place in ImageVew. Without diving into the internal machinery of ImageView it is hard to guess why it's so.

Maybe someone would suggest another approach or workaround to override minHeight with 0 when drawable is already set on ImageView.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to alter the minHeight attribute programmatically within your code, once you know the actual image dimensions. ImageView inherits a method `setMinimumHeight(int)` from the View class.

[Android Docs - View](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setMinimumHeight%28int%29)